# Customized report generation in git repo under insight

Tags: git, graph, automation, repository, report

I am trying to create a report(with issue details) in git repo similar way how insight tab has.

Is it possible to generate a graph in git repo with issues+pull request data and made it accessible to every one similar way how insight has merge, pr, issue details up to date?

Data Example:

[image: Data of issues]

Graph generated using this data.

[image: Graph by Issues]

Insight has default graphs as shown below. Wanted to add above graph too in it.

[image: Other graphs inside insight by default]

Comment: git does not store Issues or PR **messages** . Both Pull Requests and Issues are Github specific features. So for generating such report, you should probably see Github API

Comment: Hi Jdeep, Thank you for prompt response,  I had collected  data using Github API into a excel, now using that data I need to generate(automate) graph in git repo, similar way how in insight we have. Is it possible? If its yes , then how can we.

Comment: Okay. There are ways to show real time data on github. But you cant show the graph in the Github Insights Tab. You can generate a jpeg of the graph through a custom made API and then put the url of that jpeg into your README.md or other markdown files. I have not done something like that before, but you can try [Google Dynamic Graph API](https://developers.google.com/chart) for live data representation.